# Extract Data from Varbinary Column and save it in its original format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bcp, varbinary

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a `varbinary` column `RelatedData_img` in the table `Reminderimage`. In that column I store Word, Excel files, images (png, bmp or jpg format) or text files etc. Now I want to store data from that column to a disk using command.

I have tried to use this `BCP` command:

```
bcp "SELECT RelatedData_img FROM Reminderimage.dbo.Reminderimage" queryout "D:\testing6" -n -S PCname\SQLMANAGEMENT,25222 -Utest -Ptest
```

I get the file which contains xml files. I have tried `-N` and `-c` instead of `-n`. But I get the same xml files.

How can I get the files in original format (word , excel, jpg etc). I want to store all the column contents at a stretch because I don't know which row has which format file.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

- [Create a format file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx) for the query with one column (say, `C:\Temp\xyz.fmt`).
- Edit the format file to set the prefix to 0 bytes (eg using Notepad).

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
CREATE TABLE tt(the_file VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL);
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @bcp_cmd VARCHAR(8000);
SET @bcp_cmd='BCP '+QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())+'.dbo.tt format nul -T -N -f "C:\Temp\xyz.fmt" -S PCname\SQLMANAGEMENT,25222 -Utest -Ptest';
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @bcp_cmd;
DROP TABLE tt;
GO
-- This creates C:\Temp\xyz.fmt file with prefix=8... Change the 8 to 0 in it.
```

---

- Use the format file in your BCP export command. You will have to use a cursor to loop through the records you wish to export, and generate a dynamic BCP command for each file you wish to generate. This is an example that selects the first row from the table in your question, and exports it do `D:\testing6`.

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @bcp_cmd VARCHAR(8000);
SET @bcp_cmd='BCP "SELECT TOP 1 RelatedData_img FROM Reminderimage.dbo.Reminderimage" QUERYOUT "D:\testing6" -T -fC "C:\Temp\xyz.fmt" -S PCname\SQLMANAGEMENT,25222 -Utest -Ptest';
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcp_cmd;
GO
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, it just copies a file to D:\ with name testing6. How to decide the extension of this file ?

Comment: @ITresearcher If you didn't store the format of the file in your database, you would have to inspect the binary data yourself. There's no functionality in SQL Server to auto-magically detect what format the file is in.

Comment: In the mentioned site i didn't find method to create a format of column. Procedure of creating fmt file for table is explained. Can you help me how to create a fmt file of 'RelatedData_img' column in my case.

Comment: @ITresearcher The statement to create the format file is in my answer (the first snippet).

Comment: the contents of fmt file is as given,                                       10.0
3
1 SQLINT 0 4 "" 1 Imageid ""
2 SQLINT 0 4 "" 2 Autonumber ""
3 SQLIMAGE 0 0 "" 3 RelatedData_img.                                  When I run this in your second query I get error, "Host-file columns may be skipped only when copying into the Server"

Comment: @ITresearcher You did not get that by executing that first snippet, no way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104987/discussion-between-it-researcher-and-tt).

Comment: I got a command to extract all the contents to a .dat file "bcp "SELECT Name FROM AdventureWorks.Sales.Currency" queryout Currency.Name.dat -T -c" but now I dont know extract the contents of that dat file. Can you help me in this ?

Comment: @ITresearcher I suggest starting a new question... the comments section is not the right place ...